# Rearrange iPhone apps

Tags: ios, iphone

On my iPhone5S I wanted to rearrange some apps to be on the 1st screen in iTunes. This appears to be almost impossible (at least for anyone over the age of 65). iTunes keeps dropping apps I am trying to move into a group. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: So, long press and hold the app icon to be rearranged and then drag it to the desired screen would be the standard approach. I'm not sure what you mean by "iTunes keeps dropping apps..."? cf. http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200290

Comment: Unfortunately dragon drop does not work for those with limited manual dexterity. Releasing the pressure at the wrong time creates a "group" with the unfortunate target.  I am looking for an alternative approach, with a more predictable outcome.

Comment: Sticky Keys? System Prefs > Accessibility > Keyboard [or there may be a 'click-hold' equivalent in trackpad, but I don't have one so can't see the prefs pane.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your iPhone to iTunes and then rearranging your apps this way: navigate to 'Apps' category and double click on the screen from where you want to move any App and then drag it to the desired screen?